# For a Stress Test on an application in jmeter should we increase the transaction per hour or No of users?

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

If we have to do a Stress test on a application do we need to increase concurrent users or transaction per hour. I am confused with transaction per hour and No of concurrent users.
If i am given with both concurrent users and Transaction per hour ,Do i need to calculate User based on transaction per hour (using Little's law) or consider the given concurrent users?

Comment: How many transactions will each user perform?  Have you written the SQL for your application yet?  What is the purpose of the Stress test?  Is the Stress test running artificial queries or _your_ queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a well-behaved JMeter test a thread (virtual user) must represent a real user with 100% accuracy including i.e. reasonable [think times](https://dzone.com/articles/performance-testing-with-a-think-time)

The most popular question from the business is "how many users does my application support", "hits per second" is a different metric and normally it's higher due to concurrent downloading of i.e. embedded resources (images, scripts, fonts, styles, sounds, etc.) and executing [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) requests

So I would recommend ramping up **users** as reducing think times will lead to improper real life application usage simulation.

More information: [What is the Relationship Between Users and Hits Per Second?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-relationship-between-users-and-hits-second)